# why nagios disable notification setting is flapping?

Tags: nagios

I have nagios 3.0.3. I have disabled the notification on one of the service. Now if I continuously refresh the `service details` page the `notification disabled icon` keep appearing and disappearing.

I did this originally this setting to stop mail notification on this flapping service. However I also keep receiving the mail notification.

How do I investigate whats wrong.

The same setup was working fine. On a given day my disk went 100% usage. And since then its showing this behavior.

I tried restarting nagios service but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Things came back to normal when I rebooted the machine. Surprising.